# Filtering data in a reducer then attaching it to a component with { connect } from 'react-redux';

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Please correct me if I'm wrong, because I've heard different stories with using redux with react. I've heard that you should have all your logic in your reducers, I've also heard that the store should be your single source of truth.

That said, I'm taking the approach where my logic, that is filtering stuff from json file is in a reducer file. Then I call the actions to filter out different parts of the json and return it,

```
    import Data from "./BookOfBusiness.json";

    const initialState = {
    TotalData: Data
    };

    const filterDataWTF = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState = { ...state };
    let itExport = newState.TotalData;


    if (action.type === "Status55") {
        let itExport22 = {...itExport};
        console.log("came to Status55 and itExport value is " + itExport22); // comes undefined. WHY??

        return itExport22.filter(xyz => {
        if (xyz.Status55.includes("Submitted")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
        });
    }

    return itExport;
    };

    export default filterDataWTF;
```

the problem is my variable itExport22 is showing up as undefined. Any tips please. TYVM

Comment: you shouldn't use logic in your redux. But there is only one reason to your variable is   showing wrong. Check your Json File. It has to have a json valid. Like so: [{"id":1, "name":"string name"}].

Comment: @GasparTeixeira hi the json is valid, and during the mapStateToProps the json is properly formatting, it is during the dispatch is crashes.

Comment: Are you combineReducers properly? check this codesandbox so we can share the scenario you are working in. https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-field-nlmu7

Comment: @GasparTeixeira yes sir if the combined reducer did not work right, the initial mapping itself would not worked . will try to put something up later

Comment: @GasparTeixeira did you make that https://codesandbox.io/ for me ^-^?

Comment: Actually I used this redux another day. I was helping another guy. So I adapted your json file and test it before I give you an answer.

Comment: @GasparTeixeira thank you sir, I've attached a file called test.js did not attach it to your redux( did not want to break anything) , and even updated the bookofbusiness.json with some of my code... It kinda works the number of times, "Submitted" shows up with "Status55". HOWEVER i need it to return that node if it mataches and not just true.. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay once we got something working that you can vote for an answer, lets write an answer for you.

In that case your filter is returning a boolean. You should do something like so:

```
return itExport22.filter(xyz => xyz.Status55.includes("Submitted"));
```

Returning an empty array you are sure that you are receiving the same type on your component.

Your filter is fine. Only this should work

Comment: so it did return the 'xyz' when using console.log( I updated the test.js a bit more). however I would think it would return that 'xyz', but I still get that undefined error. a better question is the logic used is to filter out all the nodes should have return as I was using return xyz.. then why did the map to where this was called not.

Comment: I'll give you a vote, regardless thank you for all your help

Comment: your state is object that contains array you should return an object

Comment: yes the state is the object... but does that get updated after firing the filter?  I'm going ahead and attaching the component where this is being called. it is called Books.jsx

Comment: javascript filter array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned. if you have a return will be always an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should always return the new state

your reducer return type is boolean or itExport22 but it's should be object contains TotalData

Comment: sorry i do not follow, I made  a minor change where let itExport22 = {...itExport}; is a clone. How would it be a boolean when itExport22 is a copy of itExport?

Comment: you should return your new state {...state, TotalData: itExport22 }